# JQuery event listeners match cases

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I used to work with jquery for event handling in webpages.
Last few days I met with a problem on initializing the events.

I add a simple example to make my question more clear. We will consider about `click` event for now.

For click event of `<div id="ex"></div>` I usually write something like

**Method 1**

```
$('#ex').click(function(e) {
  //code
});
```

and also I know we can write,

**Method 2**

```
$('#ex').on('click', function(e) {
  //code
})
```

**Method 3**

```
$(document).on('click', '#ex', function(e) {
  //code
})
```

> Now the problem is I saw only few of the element's events are working
>   **only** for **method 3**. At the same time I have method 1 and method 2 for other element in the same file, they are working perfectly. But
>   only few elements and not following the method 1 and 2.

What may be the reason? Is this related to my css? How can I understand that where to use method 1 and method 2 and method 3?

Comment: Could you possibly have any issues with conflicting libraries? Are you loading multiple jQuery versions, or otherwise anything that could be in conflict with your current library? Also, since you only provided the methods, make sure that your logic fits the uses of your methods. The answer from @baj9032 covered the uses of the methods you listed in your question.

Comment: Currently I am loading jquery 3.3.1 and also I am using jquery ui library

Comment: Which one are you loading first, and which one are you loading last? Try to load the jQuery UI library first, then load jQuery 3.3.1. Also take note of my edited comment up top, and the answer by @baj9032 below.

Comment: I tried by changing the order. It didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When the element already exists in the dom, then you can use first method.
2. When you want to attach multiple events like click, blue, etc., then you can use the second method.
3. When your element does not exist in the dom, but it is dynamically injected into the dom, then you can use third method.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Now I could see the relationship. Elements which are initially `display:none` are looking for the method 3. What is the impact of it?

Comment: The style of the element does not matter, it's how the element was loaded in correlation to your Javascript. Remember, Javascript and HTML is read top-down by the compiler, so if you have any JavaScript that *"does something"* before the element is loaded, then *"that something"* won't work, as @baj9032 described. If your element exists upon the execution of certain JavaScript function, then method 1 will work and method 2 will work. However, if new elements are dynamically added, you will have to use the 3rd method.

Comment: @Ramesh: when element exists on the page with display:none then you can not click on that element but when element displayed on the page then its click event listener is working.